# Get status of multiple long running PHP scripts.

Tags: php

First and foremost: please not that this post isn't about Ajax/PHP status updating. It's pure PHP, my script needs to be able to run in console. Be gentle with that dup' question. Thank you.

I have a web application that starts multiple long running operations on multiple remote servers. The output is in the same format for all those scripts. My master script needs to retrieve the status of all those scripts and then process them and output the result.
So far, I've tried:

- Start the remote process then poll results from a `check_status.php`, who shares the status array via transparent session variables. I found it to be too error/failure prone, and couldn't have a really solid implementation of it.
- Stream the output of the server, and find each time the last status JSON string and use it. But this also felt, well, clumsy.

I'm sure I'm missing something. So I'm asking for your help. 
My solution requires:

- **No** additional packages to be installed. (e.g PEAR, PECL....)
- Works on PHP 5.3.
- Preferably, (but not necessary to post a solution, I'd be just grateful) using rmccue/Requests.

Comment: Use a shared data store e.g. DB, that all can access?